# Rails Ruby version issue Mac M1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-m1

I've got a problem with ruby versions, working on mac M1.

I tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67247043/m1-mbp-rails-dbcreate-is-throwing-an-error-for-msgpack), and installed ruby 2.7.3 via rbenv. But I'm still running into the following problem:

`rails webpack:install` results in `Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.3`

However, when I look for `ruby --version` I get `ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [arm64-darwin20]`.

Just to be clear, I want to work with ruby `2.7.3` as that seems to be better working on Mac M1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to restart the terminal? perhaps the session in which the app is open didn't update with the new ruby version.

Comment: Checkout my article - https://medium.com/@vishalsadriya1224/how-to-install-postgresql-node-with-nvm-ruby-with-chruby-rails-in-macbook-pro-m1-chip-4612e0a50260

Answer (score 3):

ok, so I found the solution, there were several things wrong.

I didn't have .ruby-version file, so I created one and input `2.7.3`.

As mentioned in the comment, restarting the terminal helped pinpoint the problem further, as after the restart `ruby --version` now outputted `2.6.3`.

I tried to rerun `rbenv install` and `rbenv global 2.7.3` but with the same results.
I found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version) about rbenv not updating ruby version, and I realized I didn't have a `./zsh_profile` or `./bash_profile` (on Mac you can check if you have such a file by pressing `Cmd + shift + .`).

If you don't have such a file, create it via `vim ~/.bash_profile`. Type `i` to write and insert `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`. Hit the `esc` key and type `:x` to exit vim mode.
Then run `source ~/.bash_profile`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860269/13801110) for more information. If you have it, make sure you have the same content as described above.
The important point is that you see `shims` when you run `echo $PATH`.

I then restarted the terminal again and `ruby --version` gave the correct version.

I rerun `bundle install` and `gem install rails`. I further had to rerun `rails webpack:install` before the rails server was actually working.

Comment: Super! It works on my M1.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Gemfile and .ruby-version file. If you don' have .ruby-version, add it and insert ruby version you want (2.7.3) then bundle install.

Comment: nope. both gemfile and .ruby-version file already have the version I want (2.7.3.) and I've already done a bundle install before posting the question...